# How to make a vector from columns of data.frame in R?

Tags: r

here is the detailed description:
A dataframe like:

```
name height weight  
john   6     160    
mike   6.2   155    
jack   7     180
```

I want to make a new column which is the combination of the last two columns:

```
height_weight    
c(6,160)    
c(6.2,155)    
c(7,180)
```

I think this is easy with for loops. I am trying to find a more efficient way

this transform is useful because many methods f need input=c(x1,x2) instead of input = ..., if you want get result of each element of the column
you can use sapply/lapply(height_weight,f)

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. What you show as expected output are three vectors and not a column.

Comment: I want a column(actually the type of the column is a list) which has vector as its element

Comment: I think you are vastly overestimating the usefulness and underestimating associated inconveniences. Experienced R programmers would keep the columns separate.

Comment: I need put them together not because I used to do that or I like that, just because the result need to come to another big function in a big package which need the input like body_index=c(x1,x2), and I don't want to modify that big function

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. Give us the function and we can tell you how to feed it the input without modifying your data to such an unusual (and bad) format.

Comment: That's fine, I already got the result of what I wanted in an efficient way, and I think this "bad" format plays a key role, I think you call it "bad" may because it has more than one values for a column which may not good for traditional data base, but you need to break some frame if it can not fit the current model, that is why nosql so popular these days

Comment: You are free to do this, but your premise is wrong. You could probably simply apply that horrible (because not vectorized and therefore slow) function with `apply(DF[, c("height", "weight")], 1, f)`.

Comment: Your solution is good use of apply by row margin, but it is slower in this case, may be due to transform a dataframe to a matrix, and the output of apply is not flexible,  But you may be right on : there may be another way to solve the premise of this question and thanks for raise that wisdom

Comment: I do not believe that any other solution proposed in the answers will be faster. E.g., transposing a data.frame also returns a matrix and then you loop the function over the observations.

Comment: argue is useless, try another way and compare them by performance time, you will see the difference,

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to create a `list` of `vector`s.  Assuming that the OP needs a `list` column

```
df1$height_weight <- do.call(Map, c(f= c, unname(df1[-1])))
df1
#  name height weight height_weight
#1 john    6.0    160        6, 160
#2 mike    6.2    155    6.2, 155.0
#3 jack    7.0    180        7, 180
```

Comment: So the cool thing of the function:Map is that it worked with each row of the data frame instead of each col of the data frame

Answer (score -1):

Actually I think there is another way to do this logically
since all apply family function work with the columns not the rows

make a transpose of the columns of data.frame 
then you can use lapply on the transposed data.frame
and transpose you result back

Answer (score -1):

As much I can understand, Guess you are looking for this

```
data$height_weight <- paste(data$height,data$weight,sep = ",")
  name height weight     height_weight
1 john    6.0    160   6,160
2 mike    6.2    155 6.2,155
3 jack    7.0    180   7,180
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I mean